# How do I get the correct data out of a observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to get the data out of a observable but i'm not getting the correct data.
This is my get call to my API

```
    getLastxScans(amount: number): Observable<Scan[]> {
    return this.http.get<Scan[]>(`${this.ROOT_URL}/Scan/amount/${amount}`);
  }
```

Which returns this when i subscribe to it

```
{scans: Array(30)}
```

When i try to fill a Scan[] with this data it doesn't work.
Do I need to go deeper into the object to extract the data?
If so how do i do this? I've tried doing it this way

```
    this.deviceService.getLastxScans(this.scanAmount)
      .subscribe(scans => this.scans = scans);
```

And this way

```
this.deviceService.getLastxScans(this.scanAmount)
    .subscribe(res => this.scans = res.scans);
```

Comment: you just need supply the proper type to the `get` type parameter, and then inference will work for you: `return this.http.get<{scans: Scan[]}>(url).pipe(map(res => res.scans))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use: *(since the array is the value of the `scans` key of the response)*

```
this.deviceService.getLastxScans(this.scanAmount)
    .subscribe(res => this.scans = res.scans);
```

---

From the comments, you could also do:

```
getLastxScans(amount: number): Observable<Scan[]> {
   return this.http.get<Scan[]>(`${this.ROOT_URL}/Scan/amount/${amount}`)
              .pipe(
                 map((res:any) => res.scans)
              );
}
```

Comment: Should've added that I've already tried that aswell. res already gets recognised as a Scan[] so it won't have that as a property

Comment: Change `this.http.get<Scan[]>(\`${this.ROOT_URL}/Scan/amount/${amount}\`)` to `this.http.get(\`${this.ROOT_URL}/Scan/amount/${amount}\`)` in that case then coz the api returns an object `{}` and not an array `[]`

Comment: Still no luck even after I removed the Observable<Scan[]> from the method aswell

Comment: That is because you typed it like that. Try: return this.http.get<Scan[]>(`${this.ROOT_URL}/Scan/amount/${amount}`).pipe(map(res => res.scans))

Comment: Property 'scans' does not exist on type 'Scan[]'. Which i find a weird error since I can't write the initial values to a Scan[]

Comment: @NicholasK, that's why I prefer your answers over others. You explain everything everything very well.

Comment: It looked like that worked, although the list itself doesn't get filled yet. The data itself looks correct though
`
this.deviceService.getLastxScans(this.scanAmount)
      .subscribe(res => this.scans = res);
    console.log(this.scans);
`
the console.log shows me a empty array.
Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: The `console.log(this.scans)` should be within the *subscription* block as its value gets assigned *asynchronously*.

Comment: Thank you @NicholasK, now I have another question how do I make the webpage update once this data gets in so that it can be visualized.

Comment: You're welcome. That should be pretty straight forward. You can use *ngIf to determine whether the data is ready and then render it on the template.